# While while debugging eclipse open another java file with same name

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am using Eclipse 2019-03, Java 8 .
I have 2 wars say A and B and both have file named C.java. I have but breakpoint at B war's C.java but at time of debugging A war's C.java gets open. Please tell which settings need to be done to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all opened workspaces.
2. Reopen your workspace.
3. Remove all breakpoints.
4. Reset the breakpoint.
5. Start debugging.

And see if the problem is gone.

Comment: no the problem remains there.. i need both the wars .